# How to detect if any child elements within a parent element has a certain class?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if any of the sub-divs within the parent "gallery" div have a class of "show".

```
<div id="gallery">

<div class="show"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</div>

if (TEST CONDITION) {
   alert('sub element with the class show found');
} else {
   alert('not found');
}
```

It doesn't have to be in a if/else format. To be able to do this in a jQuery chainning sort of way would be better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do:

```
if ($("#gallery > div.show").length > 0)
```

Comment: +1, although you could omit the comparison, since it appears that `0` will equate to `false` anyway.

Comment: That's fair enough, and is, and depends entirely upon, personal preference. :)

Answer (score 9):

if you wish to keep jQuery chaining capability, use:

```
$("#gallery").has(".show").css("background","red"); //For example..
```

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
$("#gallery div").each(function (index, element) {
if($(element).hasClass("show")) {
//do your stuff
}
});
```