# .find() relationship with loops, each() and this keyword - .find() returning 4 when it should only be 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if a `<ul>` exists inside an `<li>` that has the class `.sub-menu` and if it does, add a class to the anchor tag inside the `<a>` tag above the `.sub-menu`

[Using jQuery to see if a div has a child with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539162/using-jquery-to-see-if-a-div-has-a-child-with-a-certain-class)

[How to detect if any child elements within a parent element has a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844886/how-to-detect-if-any-child-elements-within-a-parent-element-has-a-certain-class)

Above are my reference answers.

I'm trying to loop through each list and check with `.find()` I don't understand how to use `.find()` in a loop or `each()` function and how to tie it to the `this` keyword.

I also tried `.children()` but it throws that children() is not a function

See the first example below.

```js
$(function(e) {
var getMenuItems = $(".item");
  for (var i = 0; i < getMenuItems.length; i++) {
    if (this.find("ul.sub-menu") !== 0) {
      console.log("sub-menu found")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

it throws `this.find is not a function` - why? Can you not use `this` in `.find()`?  Is `this` not referring to what I think it is?

I don't understand.

I tried this too:

```js
$(function(e) {
var getMenuItems = $(".item");
  for (var i = 0; i < getMenuItems.length; i++) {
    if (getMenuItems.find("ul.sub-menu") !== 0) {
      console.log("sub-menu found")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The error goes away, but it logs 4 times when I expect it to be 2. This is because it's just looping 4 times I think? Howcome `.find()` doesn't work in this example? What is `this` exactly referring to in these examples? My understanding was that if you use `this` in a loop it's referring to each element it's looping through. But I guess that's not the case.

What needs to change with this code snippet so that I can hit the 2 sections with `.sub-menu` and modify the DOM accordingly?

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is there.

Comment: It logs 4 times because there's 4 things you are looping over.

Comment: You also don't actually need to do any looping here. Just select your target elements and do work, looping will occur implicitly.

Comment: Did you mean `$(this)` in the first attempt? If so, you probably meant `$(this).find("ul.sub-menu").length !== 0`

Comment: Want to know what `this` is.... log it to console ...`console.log(this)`

Comment: @charlietfl I think I missed it in my question but it logs the entire DOM and not the list element. Why does it do that?

Comment: Because nothing in the loop changes it from what it is outside the loop and it has nothing to do with the list items to begin with. It is what `$(function(){ })` scopes it to be

Comment: [How does `this` keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @trincot oh right I forgot - that is what I meant and why I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using jQuery so you can use `each` method to achieve what you looking for. See snippet in below:

```js
$(function(e) {
  var getMenuItems = $(".item");
  getMenuItems.each(function( index ) {
   if ($(this).find("ul.sub-menu").length > 0) {
      console.log("sub-menu found")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Version not relevant... `each` has been the same since beginning of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- In the callback passed to `$()`, `this` is the document DOM object. On the other hand `.find` is a jQuery method -- not a DOM method -- so that explains the error in the first attempt. Note that in general you should use `$(this)` in jQuery callbacks (there are exceptions), which then allow you to call methods like `.find`.
- The comparison with zero is not the right way to test if `find` returns a match. `find` returns a jQuery object which is array-like, so you should really do this:

  ```
  if ($(this).find("ul.sub-menu").length !== 0)
  ```
- Although `$(this)` now returns a jQuery object, it is the *same* object in each iteration of the `for` loop, and so you get 4 outputs, and in each case the tested `.length` value is in fact 2. You actually want `this` to refer to the elements in `getMenuItems`. For that use the callback passed to `getMenuItems.each`. In there `this` will refer to an "item" element. So then the above `if` condition will become correct:

  ```
  getMenuItems.each(function () {
      if ($(this).find("ul.sub-menu").length !== 0) {
          console.log("sub-menu found");
      }
  });
  ```

But I would suggest to not use `find` at all, but a smarter selector:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".item > ul.sub-menu").each(function () {
       console.log("sub-menu found");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu"><li>Sub A.1</li></ul>
   </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">C</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu"><li>Sub C.1</li></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">D</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```